# Is this function known as a special function?

Tags: special-functions

Let the function (of $z$) be defined by the formula
$$
\int \limits_1^\infty\frac{dt}{t^{\large z}\sqrt{t^2-1}}.
$$
Is it known as a special function?

Comment: If it converges, it is known as particular case of a constant function.

Comment: Please observe t^z in the denominator.

Comment: It looked like a $2$. Let me help you with that.

Comment: It is a [ratio of two gamma functions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate[t^%28-z%29+1%2FSqrt[t^2-1]%2C{t%2C1%2CInfinity}]&dataset=).

Comment: Ok, I will write the details of the derivation.

Comment: And if $Re\, z>1$, it seems the same formula holds?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This integral can be written in terms of beta/gamma functions. Namely, making change of variables
$u=\frac{t^2-1}{t^2}$ transforms it into
\begin{align}
\int_0^{1}\underbrace{(1-u)^{z/2}}_{=t^{-z}}\times
\underbrace{\sqrt{\frac{1-u}{u}}}_{=(t^2-1)^{-1/2}}\times \underbrace{\frac{1}{2}(1-u)^{-3/2}du}_{=dt}=\\
=\frac12\int_0^1u^{-1/2}(1-u)^{z/2-1}du=\\
=\frac12 B\left(\frac12,\frac{z}{2}\right)
=\frac{1}{2}\frac{
\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{z+1}{2}\right)}
=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{
\Gamma\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{z+1}{2}\right)}.
\end{align}